# configure: error: Cannot find OpenSSL's <evp.h> - Installing php imagick in Mac OS 10.9.4

Tags: php, imagick, ampps

Tried to install imagick in my php 5.3 (AMPPS)

I saw instructions in net to do this command but there's an error

brew install php53-imagick

```
==> Installing php53-imagick dependency: php53
==> Downloading http://www.php.net/get/php-5.3.29.tar.bz2/from/this/mirror
######################################################################## 100.0%
==> Patching
patching file configure
patching file configure.in
patching file Zend/zend_language_parser.y
patching file configure
patching file Zend/acinclude.m4
==> rm Zend/zend_{language,ini}_parser.[ch]
==> ./configure --prefix=/usr/local/Cellar/php53/5.3.29 --localstatedir=/usr/loc
checking for krb5-config... /usr/bin/krb5-config
checking for DSA_get_default_method in -lssl... no
checking for X509_free in -lcrypto... yes
checking for pkg-config... no
configure: error: Cannot find OpenSSL's <evp.h>
```

How do i fix this?

My PHP,Apache,Mysql is installed using AMPPS

Comment: I am having the same issue, any help is greatly appreciated. I have libssl-dev installed and can confirm the presence of evp.h.

Answer (score 0):

I know I am late but future users can follow [this](http://www.softaculous.com/board/index.php?as=e2tcialagwgqmpemkkwtu1z8dw5mbjov&tid=5246&title=switching_from_MAMP_to_AMPPS_for_redis#p19026) post.

Download the PHP Extension Source first

`user> cd /src/of/php/extension`

`user> /Applications/AMPPS/php/bin/phpize`

**Note:** Below command is just to get the option list

`user> ./configure --help`

**Note:** options below can be fetched from `--help` which you executed above.

`user> CPPFLAGS="-m32 -I/Applications/AMPPS/extra/include -I/any/other/inclue/path" CFLAGS="-m32" LDFLAGS="-L/Applications/AMPPS/extra/lib -L/any/other/lib/path" ./configure --option1=value1 --option2=value2`

`user> make`

`user> sudo make install`

You will have to move the extension to extension directory and enable it from PHP Extension of Ampps.

Comment: Good plan, didn't work.

I prefixed my ./configure with this environment variable and it worked `PHP_OPENSSL_DIR=yes`

Answer (score 0):

Answered on [server's fault](https://serverfault.com/a/747413/51691).

You need to help configure figuring out where to look for the evp.h file, because by default it will scan for directories and add hardcoded suffixes to them to find it. I've kept the details in [my wiki page](https://ychaouche.informatick.net/phpevp.h) for those who want to understand the solution. Here's what worked for me :

```
root@audio-mon[10.10.10.82] ~/DOWNLOADS/php-5.5.23/ext/mysqlnd # PHP_OPENSSL_DIR="/usr /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu"
root@audio-mon[10.10.10.82] ~/DOWNLOADS/php-5.5.23/ext/mysqlnd # ./configure --with-libdir=""
[...]
checking for DSA_get_default_method in -lssl... yes
checking for X509_free in -lcrypto... yes
checking for pkg-config... /usr/bin/pkg-config
checking for OpenSSL version... >= 0.9.6 #                     <------------------------------------- YES !
[...]
config.status: creating config.h
config.status: config.h is unchanged
root@audio-mon[10.10.10.82] ~/DOWNLOADS/php-5.5.23/ext/mysqlnd #
```

YMMV (paths are different). If that didn't work for you [check the wiki page](https://ychaouche.informatick.net/phpevp.h), it will help you figure out what paths to put.